# Function comparison

Tags: python, performance

I was doing this leetcode question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/find-positive-integer-solution-for-a-given-equation/

My code was:

```
res = []
for x in range(1,1001):
    for y in range(1000,0,-1):
        test = customfunction.f(x,y)
        if test == z:
            res.append([x,y])
return res
```

but this timed out,
a solution was:

```
 def findSolution(self, customfunction, z):
    res = []
    y = 1000
    for x in xrange(1, 1001):
        while y > 1 and customfunction.f(x, y) > z:
            y -= 1
        if customfunction.f(x, y) == z:
            res.append([x, y])
    return res
```

given the for loop and the while loop. it seems like these two functions do exactly the same thing.
Why does my code time out but the while loop doesn't?

Comment: Your version doesn't break out of the inner loop when the `customfunction.f() > z` condition fails.

Comment: Second example terminates the `while` loop as soon as `customfunction.f(x, y) <= z`. Your version does not.

Comment: You are unconditionally evaluating the function a million times, completely ignoring the given fact that it is monotonically increasing in both parameters.  For example, if the result is greater than `z`, there is no point in ever evaluating the function with a greater `x` or `y` value, because those are guaranteed to give an even greater result.

Answer (score 0):

The working version breaks out of the inner loop once the result of the custom function is reaches `z`.

You can get the same result using a `break` in the `for` loop.

```
for x in range(1,1001):
    for y in range(1000,0,-1):
        test = customfunction.f(x,y)
        if test == z:
            res.append([x,y])
        elif test < z:
            break
```

Comment: this ends up as a time limit exceeded. i think the for loops check each if case, while the while loop skips. if only there was another way to do it

Comment: The `while` loop has to execute `and customfunction.f(x, y) > z` on each iteration, so I think it should be the same.